# Simple link picker based on PHP rand() not quite working

Tags: php, random

So I want to send 5% of my traffic to each of the first three links and the remaining 85% to the 4th and final (caught with "else"). My range for rand is 1,20.

From the following code, why would I only see the 3rd (~15% of time) or 4th (~85% of time) links returned when I echo clickref_url, never the 1st or 2nd link that should each be getting 5% of the traffic?

Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

```
<?php
$rand = rand(1,20);
if ($rand == 1) {
  /* Link1 */
  $clickref_url = 'http://www.link1domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
  $clickref_url.= '&firstname='.$firstname;
  $clickref_url.= '&lastname='.$lastname;
  $clickref_url.= '&email='.$email;
  $clickref_url.= '&zipcode='.$zip;
}
if ($rand == 2) {
  /* Link2 */
  $clickref_url = 'http://www.link2domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
  $clickref_url.= '&firstname='.$firstname;
  $clickref_url.= '&lastname='.$lastname;
  $clickref_url.= '&email='.$email;
  $clickref_url.= '&zipcode='.$zip;
}
if ($rand == 3) {
  /* Link3 */
  $clickref_url = 'http://www.link3domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
  $clickref_url.= '&firstname='.$firstname;
  $clickref_url.= '&lastname='.$lastname;
  $clickref_url.= '&email='.$email;
  $clickref_url.= '&zipcode='.$zip;
} else {
  /* Link4 */
  $clickref_url = 'http://www.link4domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
  $clickref_url.= '&firstname='.$firstname;
  $clickref_url.= '&lastname='.$lastname;
  $clickref_url.= '&email='.$email;
  $clickref_url.= '&zipcode='.$zip;
}
?>
```

Comment: How large is your sample size? How many have you tracked?

Comment: Mark Baker's answer shows the root of the issue, I would also advise taking some of the improvements he mentioned. For future reference with stuff like this it's often a lot easier to test with a more simple script, e.g. replacing all the content on evaluations with `echo "Rand is equal to X, this should be hit X% of the time"`. This would make it easier to replicate and diagnose.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using an `if` test with an else for the 3/other options that overrides whatever has already been done by the first two if tests

If your initial rand is 1, it will execute the code for your `if (rand == 1)`, but also for the `else` part of `if (rand == 3) {...} else {...}`

Use `elseif`

```
$rand = rand(1,20);
if ($rand == 1) {
    /* Link1 */
    $clickref_url = 'http://www.link1domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
    $clickref_url.= '&firstname='.$firstname;
    $clickref_url.= '&lastname='.$lastname;
    $clickref_url.= '&email='.$email;
    $clickref_url.= '&zipcode='.$zip;
} elseif ($rand == 2) {
    /* Link2 */
    $clickref_url = 'http://www.link2domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
    $clickref_url.= '&firstname='.$firstname;
    $clickref_url.= '&lastname='.$lastname;
    $clickref_url.= '&email='.$email;
    $clickref_url.= '&zipcode='.$zip;
}elseif ($rand == 3) {
    /* Link3 */
    $clickref_url = 'http://www.link3domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
    $clickref_url.= '&firstname='.$firstname;
    $clickref_url.= '&lastname='.$lastname;
    $clickref_url.= '&email='.$email;
    $clickref_url.= '&zipcode='.$zip;
} else {
    /* Link4 */
    $clickref_url = 'http://www.link4domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
    $clickref_url.= '&firstname='.$firstname;
    $clickref_url.= '&lastname='.$lastname;
    $clickref_url.= '&email='.$email;
    $clickref_url.= '&zipcode='.$zip;
}
```

And as most of your lines of code are repeated, simplify it to

```
$rand = rand(1,20);
if ($rand == 1) {
    /* Link1 */
    $clickref_url = 'http://www.link1domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
} elseif ($rand == 2) {
    /* Link2 */
    $clickref_url = 'http://www.link2domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
}elseif ($rand == 3) {
    /* Link3 */
    $clickref_url = 'http://www.link3domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
} else {
    /* Link4 */
    $clickref_url = 'http://www.link4domain.com?var1='.$email.'&var2=mydomain';
}
$clickref_url.= '&firstname='.$firstname;
$clickref_url.= '&lastname='.$lastname;
$clickref_url.= '&email='.$email;
$clickref_url.= '&zipcode='.$zip;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put them in an array :-

```
$urls[1] = "http://www.link1domain.com?var1=$email&var2=mydomain&firstname=$firstname&lastname=$lastname&email=$email&zipcode=$zip";

$urls[2] = "http://www.link2domain.com?var2=$email&var2=mydomain&firstname=$firstname&lastname=$lastname&email=$email&zipcode=$zip";

$count = count($urls);
$index = rand(1,100);
if ($index > $count) { $index = $count; }
$clickref_url = $urls[$index];
```

I have only shown two but its easy to add more.

Also there is a much easier way to concatenate strings !

Comment: Another method is to use **switch(  )**